# Scala substring correctly throws IndexOutOfBounds but does not in Scala.js

Tags: scala, scala.js

In Scala REPL, when substring is called on a too short string to be cut, it throws index out of bounds, as expected:

```
scala> "123".substring(0,6)
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 6
  at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1963)
  ... 32 elided
```

But running the above in [Scala.js](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/G9NvhA7/0) does not throw an exception:

```
"123".substring(0,6)

// returns "123"
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a maintainer's answer to [an almost identical question](https://github.com/scala-js/scala-js-website/issues/130):

> That said, no, we won't make consistent, because `StringIndexOutOfBounds` is undefined behavior in Scala.js.

You can check [the documentation of the semantics of Scala.js](http://www.scala-js.org/doc/semantics.html) to confirm this claim, but this specific case with `substring` has confused me before, and should probably be called out more specifically on that page.

Comment: Thanks. The maintainer's answer eludes me, but I think I'll file a github issue and see if they'll explain it more. It definitely caught me off guard today when copying scala.js into scala jvm code.